# Compact but not semi-compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I want to find a set or space that is compact but not semi-compact ($S\subset Cl(Int S)$) (every cover by semi-open sets has a finite subcover).  So where should I look. Also semi-compact but not b-compact where b open set is $B \subset Int(cl(B)) \cup Cl(Int(B))$

> A set is b-connected if cannot be expressed as union of two disjoint non empty b-open sets where B is b-open if $B \subset Int(cl(B)) \cup Cl(Int(B))$.

So I need to find as many examples of b-connected as possible. Any ideas on this will be very helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably best looking at silly non Hausdorff spaces. For example there are no semi-compact subsets of the real line.

No semicompact subset contains an open interval. To see this suppose the set $K$ contains $(0,1)$ and consider the cover of semi-open sets $(-\infty,0], (1/n, 1-1/n), [1,\infty)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. It is easy to see no finite subcover exists.

Since $K$ contains no intervals it follows every semicompact set is totally disconnected.

It should be easy to show $K$ can have at most finitely many isolated points. Hence $K$ is a Cantor set with finitely many isolated points.

You should be able to show a Cantor set is not semicompact by a similar method to the above. Rather than choose the sets $(1/n, 1-1/n)$ you must choose an increasing sequence of open intervals where the endpoints are in the Cantor set.

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas on b-connected, and b-disconnected on similar definition?

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth You can start by trying to figure out what are the b-compact subsets of the real line.